# Will ogr2ogr correctly merge features from several OSM files to resulting set

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, osmosis

In GDAL >= 1.10, `ogr2ogr` contains [osm driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html)

I want to try this feature and migrate OSM to PostGIS (I'm aware of `osm2pqsql` existence)

I have several relatively small OSM files and wonder if `ogr2ogr` driver will merge all features correctly or do I have to use other tool for merging (`osmosis`) before migrating to PostGIS?

Comment: You might encounter problems if items are included in both datasets. I have not tested it, but it might be that ogr2ogr refuses to proceed if an object is already in the Postgis database.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how "correctly" is defined. Ogr2ogr creates by default an attribute "ogc_fid" to the target dataset and that is used as primary key. Therefore if separate OSM datasets contain the same OSM features with same osm_id they can be appended into the same PostGIS tables. Osm2pgsql will fail in this situation because it creates tables which use osm_id as primary key. However, ogr2ogr does not merge the duplicate features but after conversion they will appear many times in PostGIS tables. Because osm_id is saved also as a normal attribute it is possible to find duplicate features with SQL and keep only one and delete the rest. Therefore my answer is "Yes".

Comment: `osm2pgsql` (as least the version I tried on Windows) does not create primary key, and I guess other OS versions does not too,  as osm_id is not unique.

Comment: My version does but it may have changed:NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "planet_osm_ways_pkey" for table "planet_osm_ways" Osm_ids are unique per type node/way/relation though not universally.